# How does this SE handle questions that obviously have ulterior motives?

Tags: discussion

Recently we saw a spate of questions ridiculing , deliberately misinterpreting and spreading false stories about Hindu deities, vAnGmaya and beliefs. All of them seem to have taken their cue from the likes of  a certain contemporary anti-Hindu "preacher". They are energy-stealing and making visits to this SE tedious and unpalatable. They do not serve the purpose of expanding anyone's knowledge about Hinduism; they are not scholarly inquiries into theology or sincere dharmic investigations.

How should the SE treat such blatantly "anti-Hindu" questions? If the argument that this is not a site to promote Hinduism, the counter-argument is that  neither is it a site to denigrate Hinduism nor extend false propaganda against Hinduism.

I would say they should be deleted immediately and with extreme prejudice.

Comment: Yes, whenever you see questions (or answers) that are offensive, flag them so that they can deleted.  (And I agree that we have had a spate of recent ones.). By the way, to be clear, having factual inaccuracies isn't a reason to delete a question, but offending people is definitely a reason.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Flagging is not getting the expected results.

Comment: Well, if you think a flag was handled incorrectly, you're welcome to flag again or post about it on Meta.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan  yes flagged again but questions is/are still open.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, recently we're getting some rude/offensive like questions which sounds targeting Hinduism. Sometimes they're intentional invasion.

System is working as intended: such questions have been **heavily downvoted** and users have been blocked from posting new questions. Also if a post gets sufficient flags it gets automatically deleted by system.

So, If you observe such spam or rude/offensive posts, downvote and flag them.

We've recently deleted the question flagged twice. If user considerably behaves rude/offensive in comments with others, she/he is subjected to suspension.

Answer (score 4):

This meta Qn is quite valid and both the other answers are good. However, an important point is not yet defined:
*"Which kind of Questions are considered containing 'ulterior motives'?"*

If we keep this term undefined, then the day may come where Qn-s with genuine curiosity might also get deleted. Also, what if a user creates another ID or a different user asks a similar Qn in future? A deleted Qn makes a post untraceable and hence has more consequences than a deleted answer.

Here is a middle path:

- Edit the Qn to remove the offensive part (already suggested)
- Flag for moderator intervention if there is an edit war of reverting changes
- Moderator may temporarily **[lock the post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22229/163449)** for few hours, at an acceptable edit level
- If the user has a similar pattern, then Mods may optionally issue a warning using tools

A Qn should be deleted which has **direct** abuses, derogatory remarks or not related to the site in any way.

Answer (score -1):

> I would say they should be deleted immediately and with extreme prejudice.

Instead of deleting such questions they should be edited to remove all offensive content so it can be properly answered.

Here's a question which was heavily downvoted initially and the [system deleted it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIol9.jpg) even though another user @SwiftPushkar wrote a nice answer citing references:

> [Why Srimad Bhagavatam Canto 9 Chapter 14 insults women too much?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/18677)

So one drawback of heavily downvoting and closing prejudicial questions (for which valid answers can be provided) is that some future user will ask the exact question in the same tone and we don't have the original one (with the answer) in the system anymore to close the latter one as a duplicate.

Given that this is primarily a Q & A site, I suggest users focus on answering the central part of question (like @SwiftPushkar did with [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/18677)) instead of attacking the user in comments or flagging as 'opinion-based', 'abusive', 'offensive', etc.

As a reminder, you shouldn't [flag a question as offensive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035) simply because *you alone* find it offensive:

> ***What makes something rude or abusive and when should I flag it?***
>
> Even if a post is a bad post for some reason or another, it is probably not rude or abusive. The rude or abusive flag (formerly known as offensive) is meant to be used only in extreme cases, like hate speech, abuse against people, or abuse of the community or system.
>
> For example, if a user posts obscene images to the site, that should be flagged as rude or abusive. But if someone says something bad about your favorite technology, that probably doesn’t apply.
>
> **As a rule of thumb, if you can’t justify something being hate speech or abuse, you shouldn’t mark the post as rude or abusive. Instead, you should downvote the post.**

**Conclusion**

If you don't like a prejudicial question:

- Edit it to make it less offensive or less opinion-based.
- If you are not up for it, you can simply downvote and move along. Leave answering to other interested users.

By trying to close or delete questions (irrespective of their biased nature), you are also denying other users a chance to write answers (with proper references) and earn reputation.

Comment: The right to ask questions or to earn reputation is never at the expense of civil discourse. Nor is it anyone's right to deliberately stir up social unrest.

Comment: The question you're mentioning was deleted due to other reason: User was deleted.

Comment: @moonstar200 'Nor is it anyone's right to deliberately stir up social unrest' - agree, that's why I suggested editing and making it a useful question.

Comment: @Pandya Whatever maybe the reason the system deleted a valid question with a valid answer...

Comment: @sv The burden of editing must not be on the readers, especially when the Q is deliberately / obviously inflammatory. We flag, close, delete etc. If the user is genuinely interested in a dispassionate answer, they will have to shoulder the onus of re-asking in an honest manner.

Comment: @moonstar2001, the part mention in this answer *"some future user will ask the exact question in the same tone and we don't have the original one"* is quite valid. How will we handle that situation? From SE perspective, deletion of Qn is more consequential than deleting an answer, because the whole post is vanished. It's neither searchable in SE nor in Google. Removing the offensive part followed by locking seems more effective.

Comment: @iammilind "some future user will ask the exact question in the same tone and we don't have the original one" can't be the excuse. Many non Hindus including Muslims have asked good questions on this site. If a user genuinely wants to know reason, he should be respectful. Actually, Op here had hatred and bias against a coummunity which  is rude.

Comment: @sv. System deleted it for other reason. Not due to  abusive or rude nature(?) of his question. It was more related to user not about nature of questions.Maybe you should mention that part as it is misleading.

Comment: @TheDestroyer, suppose if the OP has a bias and his/her sole intention is to derogate the community by posting an offensive Qn. Even in such case, we can extract the genuine part from the Qn and retain it. Deleting a post can be a good immediate solution, but it will have bad consequences in future. For example, "derogatory / bias" are subjective terms. Some may feel bias and some may not. Now imagine a Mod who has a lower threshold. That Mod may delete a post quickly.

Comment: @iammilind Yes. They are subjective. It's not good to delete immediately. Many factors should be considered here. 1) Consider his previous activity 2) See whether he was blocked before by posting such offensive questions 3) Is the user genuine to accept correct interprepations (from previous questions)? and so on.. Btw, Sv misleading this answer with " Bhagavatam Women question". It has nothing do with insulting or rude. By considering many things, we will come to a conclusion whether that user is rude and came here with bias or not. Such users questions can be deleted with no mercy.

Comment: @TheDestroyer, sounds quite agreeable & reasonable. Good that Mods are considering all those factors.

Comment: "some future user will ask the exact question in the same tone and we don't have the original one (with the answer) in the system anymore to close the latter one as a duplicate." The future question will also be closed immediately and with prejudice. There is no need to mark it as duplicate of anything.

Comment: @TheDestroyer 'System deleted it for other reason....Sv misleading this answer with Bhagavatam Women question' - No I'm not misleading. If I understood correctly, there were 3 downvotes on the question initially because users wanted to stop OP from posting similar questions. Combine that with user deletion, the question itself got deleted. So what I'm saying is don't downvote heavily to the point no one is interested in answering it, instead edit it, make it useful for the community.

Comment: "The rude or abusive flag (formerly known as offensive) is meant to be used only in extreme cases, like hate speech, abuse against people, or abuse of the community or system."  I used the rude and offensive flag when the question was against community. The OP was here to promote other religions and demean Hinduism. There were duplicate accounts one after the other. .