# On allowing users with agendas

Tags: discussion

Related:  [Should we allow users with political agendas on this site?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1275/should-we-allow-users-with-political-agendas-on-this-site?noredirect=1#comment5397_1275)

On this note, should users who proselytize be allowed to post on this site. The user not only posts freely but , in spite of heavy opposition, refuses to step down as moderator. This agenda pushing must stop!

Comment: No those posts should not be allowed. Bring to Mods attention whenever you find such posts.

Comment: @Rickross One of them IS a mod.

Comment: It does not matter raise the issue whenever you find.

Comment: Isn't this proselyzation topic discussed already on the site?

Comment: @Sarvabhouma but have any systemic changes been made? This is only   a comma, not a full-stop. If there is no agenda, the user will gracefully step down as mod, will not farm reputation, will not push fallacious theories that gradually undermine the grandeur of theories that are not in alignment with his beliefs. The user is playing a long game it seems.

Comment: Thats why you should allow the free flow of ideas.  Some people may find Devdutt Pattanaik offensive, others find the pushing of the sectarian agenda of a tiny minority of Hindus offensive.  Let it all hang out, as Americans say @moonstar

Comment: Per this logic of above user @SK we should allow ISKCON as well yet evinced from the same user's leading a vindictive campaign towards banning ISKCON from the site highlights rich hypocrisy. We seriously need to be careful not to compare apples and oranges

Comment: Just an observation, there are two posts about users about propaganda. Both the posts talk about moderators in their posts. Still the reception is quite opposite. Alas! the voters on meta

Comment: @Sarvabhouma I already have a close vote even though I reference a related question. The double standards by some moderator(s) is appalling.

Comment: Why are saying only one user who is a moderator is proselytizing on the site? Didn't you read and comment thanking an answer which says ISKCON is a cult and anti Hindu, we should not follow those scriptures, we should not follow their ideology? That is not proselytizing? Some bold the text which say one must worship Shiva and Shivaa. That is not proselytizing? Users also upvote the post and comment the same. Just see the posts tagged [tag:iskcon] . Why do you say the moderator always? If you oppose what one user does, you should also include all the users doing the same against ISKCON. 1/2

Comment: @Sarvabhouma 1) I have my own questions about ISKCON (not Krishna and not believing Krishna is supreme- I have no problem with either of those. I do believe Krishna is supreme). ISKCON OTOH has become a cult-like organisation and is probably being misguided and misled by intentions that are not purely Hindu or purely Krishna. 2)Besides, someone contended that they declared themselves as non-Hindu organisation. 1/3

Comment: Always posting issue about a moderator and his way of posting looks like targetting a user. That is a bad way of posting on meta. Such questions are off-topic for meta. Add all the users and topics.  Why should a user step down as a mod when some alleges him as proselytizing due to his beliefs and personal opinions? If there is still wrong about his moderation, ask about that. There is another post on meta which asks purely about moderation. That was once deleted and once put on hold by users. Don't target users based on their personal views. 2/2

Comment: 3) It has been my personal experience that their versions of scriptures are heavily edited and interpolated and there are SIGNIFICANT differences from "original" versions. I am not cool with that. 4)My observation of said moderator is that he is playing a long game and is pushing his own personal (and political) agenda. I am definitely not cool with that 5) I have called out the other user for things that I believe are anti-Hindu in their posts. 2/3

Comment: @Sarvabhouma My request to you specifically is to look beyond  vaishnava loyalty.You incorrectly state that a user is being targeted.This person is a mod.Targeting a user & speaking out against a mod (especially when he is observed to have abused his mod privileges to suit his agenda) are very different things.Individual mod's behaviors that are inconsistent or undesirable vis-a-vis the site's purposes can be called out IMO.To comfort you,I am not against vaishnavas.I know of a very senior vaishnava scholar who was/is a devotee of Sringeri jagadguru & he also seems to be a favorite of Guru.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma Such behaviors of the Jagadgurus and senior vedic scholars are what we try to follow in our limited capacity as well.

Comment: Great! Vaishnava loyalty comes into the puicture when I ask you to bring all the users behaviour into the site's notice through your meta post. This is what I am saying. Looking at the people w.r.t their personal beliefs and faiths. Every person have questions about other faiths as right or wrong. We are not here to influence people not to follow or not to follow our faith.When a user who is mod is observed to have abused his privileges, post about it but talking about his personal views and opinions is a wrong way. There are better ways to handle these instead of meta.

Comment: Our personal views about a sect or organisation do not matter when we are on site.This site is a neutral one and we should let it be in that way.Posting questions and comments saying that sect is doing wrong and we should not follow is definitely proselytizing. We have no authority to do it. I'm talking about it and you talk about something else.When you are bringing a discussion into notice, you  should show two sides of a coin. I'm not seeking anyone's comfort. I am not talking in support of anyone.I thought this post is about a topic going on the site and not limited to a certain sect.

Comment: "We are not here to influence people not to follow or not to follow our faith." - but this user/mod tries to do just that. "post about it but talking about his personal views and opinions is a wrong way" - the abuse on several counts is to promote his personal views. You are right. It is not about a sect. However, certain behaviors on this site are exhibited by those espousing a certain sect. Unfortunately so. @Sarvabhouma

Comment: Now, I am clear that you haven't read [this comment](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1278/on-allowing-users-with-agendas?noredirect=1#comment5457_1278) and bolding the text which says we should worship Shiva and comments about not following iskcon. So, do that is not proselytizing according to you. Fine. I don't know that people who are saying not to follow and ban iskcon, who are bolding statements to worship Shiva are adherents of Vaishnava sect. Thanks for information.