# Defining Site level CoC

Tags: discussion

So there were couple of incidents happened which made me post this on meta. Events like this:

Event 1:

> @RamAbloh I don't worship shiva because he is too tamasic for my tastes. Same with his wife. ~ [Ikshvaku](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56511405#56511405)

Event 2:

> Jai Maa MahaGauri  [~ TheLittleNaruto](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/55929079#55929079) 
> https://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=1051757985285805&id=100013548405855 [~ sv.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/55929186#55929186)

Event 3:

> https://twitter.com/Avadhutwaghbjp/status/1321801126321156098
>
> > Shree **Donald Trump shall retain the office of President of America IInd time**. He wins by 4 lakh votes minimum and 9 lakh maximum but **Trump shall be blamed for managing and hacking the votes**.
>
> Is the astrologer wrong or astrology itself? [~ sv.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56085684#56085684)

Event 4:

> @TheLittleNaruto LOL! I'm no shaiva/shakta to see Apsara temples. ~ Ikshvaku

Picked couple of those; These all are targeting certain belief existing in Sanatana which is quite hurting. So, Here I am requesting fellow users to draw boundary or add extra set of site specific CoCs so that in case anyone crossing that will be warned properly.

Comment: But that user is the one who asks questions about Apasras, sex etc. isn't it? What a disgusting comment that is. How does he know that a Shaiva or a Shakta looks for Apasras temples? How absurd comment was that to make? These guys have too much hatred and at the same time very little knowledge.

Comment: "@RamAbloh I don't worship shiva because he is too tamasic for my tastes. Same with his wife."  -- That's a disgusting comment. Since this user is a repeat offender no tolerance must be shown in such cases. He has the history of getting banned. Comments should be flagged rude and abusive.

Comment: What is the current status of comment#4? I don't see any link.

Comment: You must be aware of the case of user SK, whose posts/comments used to be slightly anti-Vaishnava in nature (but nowhere near as blatantly rude like the ones here). And for that reason basically he has been banned for ages. This user must receive the similar treatment considering that he never learns from his mistakes.

Comment: I usually ignore such things. I will stay out of this for now as it seems is really hurting some/many users on this site.

Comment: @Rickross I didn't add. It's bit old conversation. My intention is to come out with certain code which won't allow users to degrade one's belief.

Comment: Sir, can you explain what is wrong with this statement - **Is the astrologer wrong or astrology itself?** and how it violates CoC?

Comment: @person There is nothing offensive in the statement but if you know sv and his comments history then we can see that he is upto something and everyone knows what that is. But you can't take any action on that individual statement I agree.

Comment: I can't see the facebook link. What was that about?

Comment: @Mr_Green It was a comically compiled video of Mamta Benarji where she is saying "Joi Mata" repetitively with some funny background music.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto"It was a comically compiled video of Mamta Benarji  .." I was not aware that sv went to this extent off late

Comment: Never forget to flag them as rude/offensive.

Comment: @Pandya Okay Noted!

Comment: @person for that to know you need to read whole conversation. Most of the messages are deleted now. But one of the moderator is aware of that conversation.

Comment: @iruvar I didn't understand.

Comment: iruvar was frustrated now he will be rejuvenated again @Pandya

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Disclaimer**: This post is just a friendly reminder.

---

#### *Be Nice*

Words/Statements which hurts other users' feelings/sentiments are never tolerated, not even on other communities in the whole Stack Exchange network. Using such statements goes against the [Code of Conduct](https://meta.stackexchange.com/conduct). Quoting from CoC:

> #### Unacceptable Behavior
>
> **No bigotry.**
> We don’t tolerate any language likely to offend or alienate people based on race, gender, sexual orientation, or religion — and those are just a few examples. Use stated pronouns (when known). When in doubt, don't use language that might offend or alienate.

And according to Code of Conduct such behaviour should be flagged to alert moderators (refer [Pandya's comment](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2057/defining-site-level-coc#comment9798_2057)).

Answer (score 2):

I **agree that the last three events are hurtful** as they are a **direct message** to the OP. I have different thoughts about the firstly mentioned event i.e

Event 1:

> @RamAbloh I don't worship shiva because he is too tamasic for my tastes. Same with his wife. ~ [Ikshvaku](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56511405#56511405)

#### My take:

Though I agree that this is an ill discussion this was **not a direct message** to the OP. This was a **casual** discussion between two different users about their beliefs and understanding.

Generally, [as Pandya mentioned](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2057/defining-site-level-coc/2060#comment9798_2057), any user going through their chat transcript felt offended by any of their discussion, can flag those comments. But from a mod's perspective, it should not be considered as action needed, because:

- This was a casual discussion and people who were discussing it have no problem with it. ([read the chat transcript here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56533843#56533843))
- The discussion was not on the [Hinduism chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15189/hinduism) where we have our own community understanding discussions to take place.

In other words, we can't restrict users to have a casual discussion about their beliefs on other **Stackexchange network chatrooms**.

If the mods or community is taking some actions (banning, avoiding, disrespecting, etc)  based on such different beliefs then we are thinking of this site as "practicing Hindu religion" but not **discussing** it. Taking action by the mods or community is clearly unwelcoming for non-Hindus.

I am mentioning all these because of my discussion with the user TheLittleNaruto on the Hinduism chatroom. [You can read the transcript here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56524428#56524428)

To put more weight on "avoiding/ignoring" (or insult), I do feel there are people who avoid others just because they have different opinions/beliefs. This should be avoided here if we really want to move this site to graduation as **one community**.

Comment: "last three events are hurtful as they are a direct message to the OP" - what exactly do you mean by this? Who is "OP" is a chatroom? How did you conclude my chat messages are responses to someone else?!