# What about this image in the user's profile description?

Tags: discussion, support

One user profile description is having the following image in it:

[image]

Obviously it is sarcastic in nature and in a way mocking the users of Hinduism.SE.

- What are the opinions of the other users here about using such an image in the profile description? Also, what is the official stand (if any) on such cases?

Comment: Related from [MSE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283942/are-there-any-rules-and-limits-about-profile-pictures). "If a profile picture is malicious, threatening, pornographic or politically inciting you can bring it to a moderators attention by adding a custom flag to one of the users posts explaining what you think the problem is." - I do not think this profile pic is any one of these

Answer (score 3):

I hope that the community will not encourage it.

It is because of the obvious reason that one should propagate negativity about the (users of) community in any manner.

In this context, I just want to share my personal experience with this issue:

During my earlier days on this site, I asked many questions on this site and the user answered some of them with nice answers. I use to read the answers and had a lot of admiration towards many avid users including the user.

After many years, with the increase in my knowledge of scriptures, I slowly able to notice that very few users are posting answers that are not from scriptures and (in fact) the answers are against scriptures. *Although the scriptural answers are available, they tend to post anti-scriptural answers.* Unfortunately, the user also became a part of it. They are using pressure points in the definition(s) of the site and push them in the negative spectrum using their knowledge, knowing about the immaturity of many users on this site.

Since most of the users are not well versed in scriptures, they tend to believe that the answers from an avid user are true and takes such answers for granted, which misleads the intention of our main site.

But, any user on our main site, does not agree with such kind of strategic acts to break down the intention of our main site. So, a natural opposition has been evolved against such users.

I think, after getting such opposition, the user is doing these acts to exhibit rant. So, it is an unwelcoming act and in my opinion, the community needs to instruct the user in some democratic form.

Comment: Answers can be many. We might agree with one answer but not all answers to a single question. My new meta post is related to this post as well. If we don't believe that answer,  better to downvote or go further by flagging but not mark the user. This is not good for site's health progress. This is all happening because of debates we have or check which spilling the beliefs of a user who is against ones beliefs.

Comment: @Mr_Green Yeah, we downvoted, we flagged, we discussed, and all the acts are the result of that

Comment: Do you mean not to discuss about the users and the intentions here?

Comment: I agree with you if moderation is active. But the elections are not yet pipelined. So, it will be a temporary issue. As you told, the silence of some people creating chaos. @Mr_Green

Comment: I believe none have any wrong intentions. If they have it will clearly fall out of CoC. If one really wants to cool things off better to not mark the user, have healthy debates in chatrooms - we might see some great questions emerging out of it, this happens when high rep users discuss. Respect every users view, respectfully disagree if needed.

Comment: @Mr_Green you may be true, but why are we posting questions about users?  Do we like it? No. But due to the inactiveness of some people, all these are emerging. You can see the change after the elections. We waited for so much time and since fewer people are trying to make the site healthier, and only one person is active in moderation., this is all happening.

Comment: Yes! I agree. Things are escalating and unfolding to something else.

Comment: "I think, after getting such opposition, the user is doing these acts to exhibit rant" -- I think that the profile description was always occupied by something that is mocking Hinduism. I have not seen all of them but one I distinctly remember was mocking Astrology which is a part of Hinduism. Some users objected to that then probably it was removed. When the same user was proposing himself as a candidate for a Mod changed the description to what some saint has written :P I could not laugh at this hypocrisy. Even I am of the opinion that "there has to be a limit to hypocrisy"  @hanugm

Comment: Also what do you think the purpose of the original meme is? Is it making fun of Facebook users as unintelligent people? It is clear that the meme is sarcastic. The user, going by his history ( and a new 40 days old user won't know that background) on this site, won't have any reason to mock Buddha but he has every reason to mock Hinduism concepts and may be even users (I understand this started to show up more after his suspension) @hanugm

Comment: That meme can be found [here](https://twitter.com/cormacrussell/status/753982806406074368?lang=en). Obviously it is making fun of Facebook/Facebook users even if light-heartedly. So, the current meme is making fun of HSE users. When this site has extra-sensitive rules regarding COC why not discuss it? We need to see with which user all this is related too. History can't be ignored. @hanugm

Comment: Yeah @Rickross, new users easily get distracted due to such acts.

Answer (score -4):

Is it just me or are there others who think HSE users are running out of things to discuss on meta that they are now nitpicking users' profiles and [messages in chat rooms](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2057)?

> *Also, what is the official stand (if any) on such cases?*

Refer to this post on MSE:

> [Is it acceptable to insult god in a user profile?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231334/is-it-acceptable-to-insult-god-in-a-user-profile)

If you find the meme in my profile offensive, feel free to report my profile at this link: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/contact

I'm also curious to know how exactly does SE Inc draw lines between freedom of speech, sarcasm and CoC.